# Newly built app version does not use new Root.plist instead of old Root~ipad.plist

Tags: ios, plist, settings.bundle

I'm working on an app that uses separate Root.plist files for iPad and iPhone: `Root~ipad.plist` and `Root~iphone.plist`. I'm trying to merge them into a single plist file by using `SupportedUserInterfaceIdioms` in a single `Root.plist` file and then deleting the ~iphone and ~ipad plists.

However, when I build directly to an iPad running an older version of the app, the settings bundle does not use the new `Root.plist` - instead it seems to be running an older `Root~ipad.plist`. How can I ensure it uses the correct plist file when the app is upgraded?

When I try updating from the older version to the new version on the simulator, it does use the correct plist file.

Testing against the iOS 7 simulator, I notice it does not use the new Root.plist, which suggests it's a problem with iOS 7 (and not 8). Do I need to do something different for iOS 7?